# How to get dynamically created javascript div id by jquery and store in php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

```
var count=0;
    function createOne() {
        var divTag = document.createElement("div");
```

> **dynamically created div**

```
        var br= document.createElement("br");
        count++;
        divTag.id = "div1"+count;
```

> **Id increment +1**

```
        divTag.setAttribute("align", "center");

        divTag.style.margin = "0px auto";
        divTag.style.width="430px";
        divTag.style.height="35px";
        divTag.style.background="olive";
        divTag.className = "dynamicDiv";

        divTag.innerHTML = "This HTML Div tag created "
                            + "using Javascript DOM dynamically.";

        document.body.appendChild(divTag);
           document.body.appendChild(br);
    }
```

**> Need to save in php using Jquery.**

```
<body>
    <h1 align="center">
    Click it
    <input type="button" id="dev" onClick="createOne()" value="GET">
    </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: On what event are you saving the div content in php by jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery then use it. Convert your function to jQuery and use jQuery's ajax functions.

JavaScript

```
jQuery(function($){

    $('#dev').click(function(){ createOne(); });

    window.count = 0;
    function createOne() {

        var new_id = 'div1' + (++count);

        $('body').append('<div class="dynamicDiv" id="' + new_id + '" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 430px; height: 35px; background-color: olive;">This HTML Div tag created using Javascript DOM dynamically.</div><br/>');    

        $.get('/div-id-saver.php', { 'id': new_id }, function(response){  
            console.log('post response:' + response);
        });

    }

});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <h1>
    Click it
    <input type="button" id="dev" value="GET">
    </h1>
</body>
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/

Answer (score 1):

** Using jQuery **

```
 // Within your createone() function 

 // Location of your PHP file
 var url = 'savemyvar.php';

 $.post(url, { div : divTag.id }).success(function(data, status, xhr)
 {
     // Do something on success
 }).error(function(data)
 {
     // Do something on error
 });
```

[Info on $.post a helper function for $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

[$.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
This will send your divTag object to the PHP script that you can use

```
$_REQUEST['div']
```

to access.

Comment: Passing the DOM object `divTag` is not the OP's intention.

Comment: Un-downvoted after the change. It was [clearly incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down).

Answer (score 1):

In your `createOne()` function, you can do an AJAX post back to a PHP script passing through the ID of the element you just created.

You can find more information on [JQuery's AJAX here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You haven't specified what you want to do with the information or when so this should help to get started.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you post the data by Ajax

```
createOne = function() {
     var $div = $('#div1'+count);
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: { id: "div1"+count, html: $div.html() }
     }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
     });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the ajax call, the data will look like:

```
var mydata = new Array ();
$("div[id^='div']").each (function (){
       mydata.push ({$(this).attr ("id") : $(this).text ()});
});
```

I use the text of the div as the value, but you can change it to your needs...